# Testing if a title is present using empty? versus blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In chapter 4 in the Rails Tutorial, I was curious if there was a reason for using `empty?` rather than `blank?` when testing to see if a title was present?  Obviously I'm new to rails but I thought the `blank?` method provided a little more flexibility.

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be because blank will evaluate to true on strings that contain  a whitespace character and because in your code page_title is initialized by default, so checking for nil is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `page_title` is being checked against `empty?` is because the default of `page_title` is a string. The contract for `full_title` expects a string and not nil.

If you were to pass in `full_title(nil)` to this method, it would blow up saying undefined method `empty?` for nil class.

In any case, `blank?` simply checks `nil? || empty?`

Comment: But currently if you were to pass in a title with empty white space `full_title('   ').empty?` it would equate to false and you would end up with a page title containing " **| Some Random Base Title** " right?  Where checking it with `blank?` would be able to catch that it's only empty white space and return just your `base_title` without the pipe. I can't see why it would really matter in this case whether you were passing in nil as an argument.  Again I am new so perhaps I'm just missing the point and my apologies if that's the case.